# How to convert the author style from capital to lower letters?

Tags: biblatex

How to convert the author style from capital to lower letter in `biblatex`?

Now I have

> KODAN A S & CHHIKARA K S. A Theoretical and Quantitative Analysis of FinancialInclusion and Economic Growth[J]. Management and Labour Studies, 2013, 38(1-2):103-133.

But I need

> Kodan A S & Chhikara K S. A Theoretical and Quantitative Analysis of FinancialInclusion and Economic Growth[J]. Management and Labour Studies, 2013, 38(1-2):103-133.

This is MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[hyperref,UTF8]{ctex} 
\usepackage[bibstyle=gb7714-2015,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=anyt,maxalphanames=2]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\addbibresource{lcgxm.bib}
\begin{document}
Thanks for your help! \\ \\
\indent \textcite{Kodan2013} \\
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bib file is as follow:

```
@article{Kodan2013,
author = {Kodan, Anand S. and Chhikara, Kuldip S.},
journal = {Management and Labour Studies},
month = {feb},
number = {1-2},
pages = {103--133},
title = {{A Theoretical and Quantitative Analysis of Financial Inclusion and Economic Growth}},
volume = {38},
year = {2013}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: This is not the output the standard `biblatex` styles produce, so you must be using a custom style that does this explicitly (or your input is wrong). Please show us a small example document that reproduces the output you are seeing at the moment with as little code as possible (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Please also add the bib-entry you are using - the error also might be there.

Comment: This is my MWE.   https://www.overleaf.com/3521114772rxbghpsxwnqx

Comment: @leelex Please edit a _truly minimal_ example into the question: that link is a full document

Comment: I have modified the MWE. It is still the link above.

Comment: Please do not post MWEs only as Overleaf links. Minimise it so much that it can be included as code directly in your question (see the two links in my comment above). Note everyone has an Overleaf account to access your project. Plus, external links are not guaranteed to remain valid and accessible.

Comment: I post MWE in my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-gb7714-2015` has an option called `gbnamefmt` that influences the formatting of names in the bibliography. Unfortunately, I don't read Chinese, but if you do, you may want to have a look at [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-gb7714-2015/biblatex-gb7714-2015.pdf).

A bit of trial and error suggests, `gbnamefmt=lowercase,` does what you want

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[
  bibstyle=gb7714-2015,
  citestyle=authoryear,
  sorting=nyt,
  maxalphanames=2,
  gbnamefmt=lowercase,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson E, Ryde U. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments[J]. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 1998, 19(4):377-395. DOI: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4⟨377::AID-JCC1⟩3.0.CO;2-P.]

For one-off changes for only a single entry, there is also the field `nameformat`.

Comment: It works! Great! Thanks a lot for your help!